# Helm - Is it possible to add values into a list and then loop over them?

Tags: templates, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I would like to create a template file which could interact with lists as regular values. Basically, loop over them.
So in other words, imagine the following 2 files:

```
values1.yaml

jobs:
  single: true
  foo: bar
  kek: bor
```

and

```
values2.yaml

jobs:
  - foo: bar
    kek: bor
  - foo: rab
    kek: rob
```

How can I create a template that works on both values files?
I personally thought of injecting the first file in a list by doing something like:

```
{{ if Values.jobs.single }}
    {{ $myList := list .Values.jobs }}
{{ else }}
    {{ $myList := .Values.jobs }}
{{- end }}
{{- range $myList }}
   ...
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work, because assignments are local (so only available within the if-else block).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helm has [a couple of functions that can inspect the type of an object](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#reflection-functions).  These generally use the Go terminology, so what you'd normally call a "list" in most languages is a "slice" in Go.

To simplify some issues around variable scoping, I'd also define the variable only once, and use the [`ternary`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#ternary) function to move the conditional inline.

```
{{- $j := .Values.jobs }}
{{- $myList := kindIs "slice" $j | ternary $j (list $j) }}
{{- range $myList }}...{{ end }}
```

In a language with more natural support for inline conditionals, this would be the equivalent of

```rb
j = values[:jobs]
my_list = if j.is_a?(Array)
          then j
          else [j]
          end
my_list.each {|dict| ...}
```